# Cuda installation on msi with two graphics card

Tags: nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics, bumblebee, cuda

I have a msi laptop CX61 2QF
  core i7,
  4GB RAM,
  Intel HD Graphics 4600,
  Nvidia Geforce 9400M,
  Ubuntu 14.04

I want to install cuda 7.0, I downloaded the run file, made it as an executable and ran on tty1 mode, disabled the lightdm and installed. Everything went well. But, after installation complete when I try to log in, the ubuntu page keep on prompting(I can't login). I have reinstalled ubuntu so many times to get this working. Every time I face a problem, sometimes a black screen pops up, but I can log in to tty1 mode. (Even when I tried to install through debian package I face the same problem).

So, I tried to install cuda without the driver, the installation was success, no problem to log in. Since I did not install the driver cuda did  not work, so when I try to install driver problems start.

Again on a fresh copy of ubuntu I tried to install only the driver, I face the same error as above.

Please help me.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when installing CUDA 7.0 on my GS60 (HD4600 + NV860M), do not install the OpenGL, it will overwrite your correct display packages which causes your problem.

My suggestion is to use **--no-opengl-libs** when running the install runfile, I have solved my problem with this. For the detailed tutorial, you can refer to the official documentation or my [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/668130/ubuntu-not-starting-post-cuda-installation/668414#668414).

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

At last, I have found the answer.
NVIDIA GeForce 940M is a new gpu. so all what you have to do is install cuda 7.5. When I install cuda with ubuntu 14.04. It worked without any problem. Bust sometimes it caused some issues. And then I installed ubuntu 15.04 with cuda 7.5 and it's working fine without any trouble.